# Regex to extract names based on patterns in values from a list of name value pairs

Tags: python, regex

I have this code

```
x = "('A', 'NN'), ('B', 'AP'), ('C', 'RB'), ('D', 'NNP')"
m = re.findall(r"\('(.*?)', 'NN[.]?'\)", x)
print(m)
```

what I want is to extract text like A B C D only if its corresponding element is NN or any extension of NN like NNP, NND.

so the output should be A and D

but the current output is `['A']`

Comment: As far as I know, `re.search()` will stop at the first match it finds

Comment: converted to findall... but it still reports A.. changed the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and use findall instead of search

```
re.findall(r"\('([^']+)', 'NN[^']?'\)", x)
```

Comment: yes... that does the trick... but can you explain why did `(.*)` did not work and your `[^']*` worked

Comment: @Knows Not Much   `(.*)` means match everything including whitespace, whereas `[^']*` means  match everything and stop as soon as you encounter `'`

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch, `.*?` matches any character, including `'`, whereas `[^']*` matches everything up to the next `'` character. Take a look at what the [`.*?` pattern](http://regexr.com/3an8p) matches vs the [`[^']*` pattern](http://www.regexr.com/3an8m)

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex solution instead, using `findall` and matched groups:

```
re.findall(r"\('([^']+?)', 'NN.?'\)", x)
```

Comment: thanks... but can you keep it generic like being able to capture and match anything instead of A-Z

Comment: Yes, let me change it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:-

```
import re 

x = "('A', 'NN'), ('B', 'AP'), ('C', 'RB'), ('D', 'NNP')"

extensions = ['NN','NNP','NND']

for a in re.findall("\((.*?)\)",x):
    test = re.search(r"^\'(\w)\',\s\'(\w+?)\'$",a)
    if test.group(2) in extensions:
        print test.group(1)
```